# WCF Client Class Name

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm wondering why When I use WCF as web service, my Class name in client changes to "MyClass"+ Client.

how can I avoid adding the "Client" Part in my WSDL?

My Service Contract :

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IOfficeEvaluation
End Interface
```

My Web Service Class :

```
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class OfficeEvaluation
    Implements IOfficeEvaluation
End Class
```

My Client ( Usage ):

```
 public partial class WebServiceSample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ws = new OfficeEvaluation.OfficeEvaluationClient();

        }
    }
```

in usage, you can see I have to get an instance of

> OfficeEvaluationClient

and The Client Part that added in the end of the class name is really on my nerves

How Can i get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching for a while I found out that the "client" part is a convention and there is nothing we can do about that.
The proxy class name is created by .NET, it looks at interface name then it drops the "I" at the beginning of Interface name and appending "Client" at the end of the name and makes a new class name.